# How to intercept JS, CSS from java script on page load

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, interceptor

I know that I can write a simple interceptor to intercept http calls. 
(function(open) {

```
(function(open) {
  vXMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {

    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        console.log(this.readyState); // this one I changed
    }, false);

    open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
  };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

This works but it does not intercept the JS file.

What I want to achieve is- Intercept the load of JS files and block them from loading. This needs to be done before page load, because I do not want that JS file to be initialized.

Comment: I don't think you can alter the way a browser is working from a webpage... Maybe i'm wrong, but it feels like a huge security breach for a browser. Moreover, it will be tough to load your script before your page. What you want to do is basically what adblocks extensions do: maybe you will want to implement a browser plugin/extension to achieve your goal.